# What does the orange hammer in the Xcode status bar signify?

Tags: xcode, xcode10

In Xcode 10 there is an orange hammer on the right side of the status bar. What does it signify? When I click on it I'm taking to the workspace build settings.

[image: orange hammer]

Answer (score 9):

Xcode 10 uses a new build system.
The legacy build system is still available in Xcode 10.
The orange hammer indicates projects configured to use the legacy build system.

Honestly I'd be concerned more about the 344 warnings